# WordPress h1 border insert after not working

Tags: css

Having trouble inserting a gold border after every first child under #content in wordpress..

```
#content .spacer h1:first-child:after{

display:block;
content:'';
width:45px;
border-bottom:3px solid rgb(229,164,20);
margin:40px 0;
padding:5px 0;
}
```

either or doesn't work

```
#content .spacer h1:first-child:after{

display:block;
content:'';
width:45px;
border-bottom:3px solid rgb(229,164,20);
margin:40px 0;
padding:5px 0;
}
```

Comment: This is useless without markup to go along with it. The rules are probably fine, its your selector string that has to match the markup.

Comment: @Bosworth99 here's a link http://tudorice.com/ (check the following pages, not the home page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am making an assumption for your HTML markup and you wanting to add a empty block with gold border after each H1 element in DIV #content.spacer.

It would be proper to use h1:nth-child(1):after

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="content" class="spacer">
    <h1>First-child</h1>
    <h1>Children</h1>
    <h1>Children</h1>
    <h1>Children</h1>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#content.spacer h1:nth-child(1):after{
  display:block;
  content:'';
  width:45px;
  border-bottom:3px solid rgb(229,164,20);
  margin:40px 0;
  padding:5px 0;
}
```

JSBIN sample here: http://jsbin.com/wejefixajiro/1/edit

Comment: I would like to be only after the title, the first h1 element.

Comment: @user2984926      <div id="content"> <div class="spacer">&nbsp;</div> <h1></h1>

Comment: @user2984926 please post your entire HTML on JSbin

Comment: @user2984926 I figured it out.. Had to change the number in parenthesis to (2).. Thanks so much for your dedication.. What's your twitter user name?